# Consume an endpoint using optional parameters in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form with 2 sections. From each section, at least one value must be selected.
I know how to pass compulsory parameters but passing the appropriate parameters based on user selection is what I am not sure of.

Any ideas please?

#### Template plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/1VhSOMi9lfBEzbQUfBWF?p=preview)

```
 <form>
  <div>
   <label>Section 1</label></br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="chkBox1" value="chkBox1">chkBox1<br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="chkBox2" value="chkBox2">chkBox2<br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="chkBox3" value="chkBox3">chkBox3<br>
  </div>
  <div>
   <label>Section 2</label>
   <div>
    Optional 1:
    <input type="text" name="fname" value="fname" />
   </div>
   <div>
    Optional 2:
    <input type="text" name="lname" value="lname" />
   </div>
  </div>
  <button ng-click="getAll()">Get result</button>
 </form>
```

#### Controller function

```
 $scope.getAll = function() {
    return $http.get('/api/testing?chbox1='+ 1 +'&chbox3=' + 1 
     +'&chbox2=' + 0 +'&optional1=' + fname +'&optional2=' + lname);
    },
```

Comment: You forgot to add your Angular controller code in your Plunkr. See my answer, if it helps you in your question or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concat your URL depending of `fname` & `lname` defined or not:

```
return $http.get('/api/testing?chbox=' + 1 + '&chbox3=' + 1 + '&chbox2=' + 0 + ((fname !== undefined) ? '&optional1=' + fname : '') + ((lname !== undefined) ? '&optional2=' + lname : ''));
},
```

I used ternary conditions for writing it faster, but you can use multiple conditions for this case too:

```
$scope.getAll = function(){
    var url;
    if (fname !== undefined && lname !== undefined)
        url = '/api/testing?chbox1='+ 1 +'&chbox3=' + 1 +'&chbox2=' + 0 +'&optional1=' + fname +'&optional2=' + lname;
    else 
        if (fname !== undefined)
            url = '/api/testing?chbox1='+ 1 +'&chbox3=' + 1 +'&chbox2=' + 0 +'&optional1=' + fname;
        if (lname !== undefined)
            url = '/api/testing?chbox1='+ 1 +'&chbox3=' + 1 +'&chbox2=' + 0 +'&optional2=' + lname;
}
```

Second option is less elegant!

Comment: Thanks @Zooly. It looks great.

Comment: @Hopez hope it's flexible enough for your need :)